# Convert string date column with format of ordinal numeral day, abbreviated month name, and normal year to %Y-%m-%d

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-dateutil

Given the following `df` with string `date` column with ordinal numbers for day, abbreviated month name for month, and normal year:

```
             date       oil       gas
0    1st Oct 2021       428        99
1   10th Sep 2021       401       101
2    2nd Oct 2020       189        74
3   10th Jan 2020       659       119
4    1st Nov 2019       691       130
5   30th Aug 2019       742       162
6   10th May 2019       805       183
7   24th Aug 2018       860       182
8    1st Sep 2017       759       183
9   10th Mar 2017       617       151
10  10th Feb 2017       591       149
11  22nd Apr 2016       343        88
12  10th Apr 2015       760       225
13  23rd Jan 2015      1317       316
```

I'm wondering how could we parse `date` column to standard `%Y-%m-%d` format?

My ideas so far: 1. strip ordinal indicators (`'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'`) from character day string while keeping the day number with `re`; 2. and convert abbreviated month name to numbers (seems not `%b`), 3. finally convert them to `%Y-%m-%d`.

Code may be useful for the first step:

```
re.compile(r"(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)").sub("", df['date'])
```

**References:**

https://metacpan.org/release/DROLSKY/DateTime-Locale-0.46/view/lib/DateTime/Locale/en_US.pm#Months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` already handles this case if you don't specify the `format` parameter:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
0    2021-10-01
1    2021-09-10
2    2020-10-02
3    2020-01-10
4    2019-11-01
5    2019-08-30
6    2019-05-10
7    2018-08-24
8    2017-09-01
9    2017-03-10
10   2017-02-10
11   2016-04-22
12   2015-04-10
13   2015-01-23
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: ok, sorry I didn't know that, the abbreviated month in this `date` column is not `%b`, correct?

Comment: Yes but if your locales are English.